# Utilização de Thread em c++

Tags: c++, thread, vector

Criei um código para verificar os números primos, mas estou tentando utilizar tds os núcleos do meu processador para calculá-los.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
vector<long long> primos;
long long pmax = 50000;

//int i;

bool isprime(__int64 num) {

    int i = sqrt(num);
    int ii = 3;


    if (num == 2) { return true; }
    else if (num % 2 == 0) { return false; }
    else if (i % 2 == 0) { i--; }


    while (ii <= i) {
        if (num%ii == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        ii += 2;
    }
    return true;

}
void prim(int ad, int thr) {
    for (int i = (3 + ad); i < pmax; i += (thr * 2)) {
        if (isprime(i)) {
            primos.push_back(i);
        }
    }

}

int tr = 2;
void p1() {
    prim(0, tr);
}

void p2() {
    prim(2, tr);
}
void p3() {
    prim(4, tr);
}
void p4() {
    prim(6, tr);
}
void p5() {
    prim(8, tr);
}
void p6() {
    prim(10, tr);
}
void p7() {
    prim(12, tr);
}
void p8() {
    prim(14, tr);
}

int main() {
    int t = GetTickCount();
    int d1, d2;
    primos.push_back(2);

    thread t1{ p1 } , t2{ p2 };//, t3{ p3 }, t4{ p4 };// , t5{ p5 }, t6{ p6 };//, t7{ p7 }, t8{ p8 };


    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    //t3.join();
    //t4.join();
    //t5.join();
    //t6.join();
    //t7.join();
    //t8.join();

    d1 = GetTickCount() - t; t = GetTickCount();
    sort(primos.begin(), primos.end());
    d2 = GetTickCount() - t;

    cout << "Tempo para calcular: " << d1 << " ms\nTempo para ordenar: " << d2 << " ms\n\n";

    system("pause");
}
```

Sempre que eu coloco mais de um thread ele retorna alguns erros.
As vezes fala o thread disparou um ponto de interrupção e as vezes que o heap foi corrompido.

Ainda sou novato em c++. Se puderem me ajudar a entender o que que aconteceu, fico grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa *proteger* o vetor de primos com um *mutex*, para que só uma thread por vez possa alterar esse vetor. Normalmente as estruturas de dados não podem ser alteradas por mais de uma thread ao mesmo tempo, isso em geral causa corrupção de memória ou outras coisas ruins.

```
// ....
// ....
#include <mutex>
// ....
// ....
using namespace std;
vector<long long> primos;
// ...
mutex globalMutex;
// ...
// ...
void prim(int ad, int thr)
{
   for (int i = (3 + ad); i < pmax; i += (thr * 2))
   {
      if (isprime(i))
      {
         lock_guard<mutex> guard(globalMutex);  // <------------
         primos.push_back(i);
      }
   }
}
// ...
// ...
```

Comment: Deu certinho
Ele só aumentou o tempo para processar, mas já melhorou bastante
Vlw ^^

Comment: então marque a resposta como aceita, por favor...